# How to choose one item in many to many relationship as special?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

What is the best practice to choose one item from a m2m relationship?
Lets say I've got an album of photos:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
  img = models.FileField()

class Album(models.Model):
  photos = models.ManyToManyField("Photo")
```

But now I also want to pick one photo as a cover. I could use a Foreign Key in Album to one Photo, but then I'd always need to check whether this photo is actually in the photos of that album. Is there a better way?

Sorry for the basic question I just somehow can't find the right words to google it.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) with a boolean `cover` that is set to `True` in case it is the cover item:

```
from django.db.models import Q, UniqueConstraint

class Photo(models.Model):
  img = models.FileField()

class Album(models.Model):
  photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, through='AlbumPhoto')

class AlbumPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cover = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['photo', 'album'], name='no_photo_multiple_times'),
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['album'], condition=Q(cover=True), name='one_cover_per_album'),
        ]
```

The first constraint guarantees that you can not add the same `Photo` multiple times to the same `Album`, whereas the second condition gurantees that each `Album` has at most one `Photo` for which `cover=True`.